# How can I make the footer of Drupal 7 theme stick to bottom of page?

Tags: css, drupal-7, footer, sticky-footer

I implemented a Bartik subtheme and modified to my taste. I'm not sure why, but the footer does not stick to the bottom of the page (unlike Bartik).

Here's the site: http://www.hashbangweb.com/.

Can anyone explain what to do to make the footer stick to the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often use [Ryan Fait's Sticky Footer technique](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/)

This would involve you slightly reworking your div structure. You would need to move the div #footer-wrapper to be on the same level as #fixed and #skip-link so it would look like:

```
<div id="skip-link"></div>
<div id="fixed"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

You'll need to ensure that #fixed has 100% height applied to it, that seems to be the main thing you're missing currently.

Hope this help.

Comment: I implemented the above suggestion, which works. I would like to make the footer the same width as the main wrapper (800px) and centered. I'd also like the content area to expand to touch the top edge of the footer. Preferably, the whole site should fill exactly 100% height of browser (without scrollbars). Any pointers? Thanks.

Comment: To make the footer 800px wide and centered, simply add the following styles to #footer-wrapper `width:800px; margin:0 auto;`

Comment: Brilliant, that worked. Any idea how to make content area meet top of footer?